# Image link download works on Python 3, but not on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

I have the following image link:
'http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/matrix/images/d/df/Thematrixincode99.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140425045724'

M unable to download it using any of the following methods on Python 2.7.13:

```
# METHOD 1
url = 'http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/matrix/images/d/df/Thematrixincode99.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140425045724'
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "local-filename.jpg")
```

and

```
# METHOD 2
resp = urllib.urlopen(url)
image_data = resp.read()
f = open('/tmp/abc.jpg', 'wb')
f.write(image_data);
f.close();
```

and

```
req = urllib2.Request(img_url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"})
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, None,15)
obj_file = open(output_file,'wb')
data = response.read()
obj_file.write(data)
response.close();
```

The output file size in each of the cases is 3KB.
How do I figure out the reason for failure of downloading the image? And is there any resolution?

UPDATE: Got an update that it works on Python 3. Need a working solution on Python 2.7

Comment: Problem is not with python version but your system. Where you are trying to download and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm able to download other images with the same code @Rahul. Have been trying it on macOS. Will try on ubuntu once.

Comment: Just realized the problem is with our local IT administration blocking this link!! I'll delete this question. Thanks @Rahul for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one more:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/matrix/images/d/df/Thematrixincode99.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140425045724")

with open("local-filename.jpg", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Well, it works for me on python 3.5. The file I get is around 2.1 mb.

Comment: Thanks for the update, will update the topic accordingly.

Comment: I just tried it on python 3 on ubuntu, and your code doesn't work. Are you sure?

Comment: As an update, all the above solutions work (even the one posted by me). The reason for failure in downloading this specific image was the IT administration blocking access to this site. Strangely I could access the same link from browser, but not using Python.

Comment: @vishal possibly a filter on user-agent or some specific proxy setting ?